# Mysql Database isn't listed but can query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql/mariadb database I can query remotely but not locally.  As root, when I'm in the mysql prompt I do show databases but it's not listed.  When I look in /var/lib/mysql my database is there as are the tables.  On the command line I can create a new database with the same name so it's like it doesn't know it exists...but it's there.  Anyone ever run into this issue?  I've restarted mariadb and the server but that didn't help.

Something else I tried is copying the /var/lib/mysql directory to a new one the changing my.cnf file to point to the new directory then did chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql2.  I started mariadb but still can't see the database.

Comment: are you using the same user in both connections? looks like a privileges issue

Comment: Yes, I am using root for both.

Comment: are you using utf8 chars by anny chance for database/tables names? Also with mysql prompt i assume you mean the mysql client program?

Comment: No, the tables use varchar and init fields only.

Comment: that is not what i meant, iam not asking about data iam asking about database names/table names..  You should provide a example see https://www.db-fiddle.com/..

Comment: (ID VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY, Serial VARCHAR(20), ATT_IMEI VARCHAR(16), VZN_IMEI VARCHAR(16), ATT_ICCID VARCHAR(21), VZN_ICCID VARCHAR(21), ATT_Phone VARCHAR(11), VZN_Phone VARCHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

So here was the problem which @Lelio Faieta's comment help me figure out.  I inherited this server from a guy who left a few weeks ago.  I decided to start from scratch by removing mariadb and reinstalling it.  In doing so I did searched for all mariadb and mysql files and found a .mysql_history with the ownership of the previous admin.  Then I remembered what Lelio wrote so I did an su as the previous admin's ID and there it was, in tact.  I took a backup of it then reinstalled mariaab and restored it as root and I'm back in business.  Thanks for those who took the time to reply.